# protect apache from CSRF with modsecurity

Tags: apache-http-server

I installed a WAF modsecurity in my ubuntu 16.04 and i tried to protect my website from CSRF attack.

Everything works right the WAF is showing access denied in modsec-audit.log but it's blocking me from accessing avec some of functions of my site are changed.

For activating the rule of CSRF, I did a symbolic link of `modsecurity_crs_43_csrf_protection.conf` and `modsecurity_crs_16_session_hijacking.conf` under my activated rules.

So maybe I have some configuration to add.
Her are result of my modsec-audit.log

```
--e631b43a-F--
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 339
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=15
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

--e631b43a-E--
```

Comment: Did you check your configuration if added it? What's your actual problem as you describe it as actually working?

Comment: how to check please !

Comment: I check my modsec-audit.log   and i can see that the WAF work successfully , but i don't understand why it block me ... and when i navigate from a private windows i'm not bloked

Comment: What does that log actually contain? How does the module actually work? Maybe your regular browser instance is blocking something?

Comment: modsec-audit.log tell you about what the WAF modsecurity is doing and it apear:Message: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "(^[\"'`\xc2\xb4\$
Action: Intercepted (phase 2)

Comment: If you do have code or log output please add it to the original question using an edit. It's usually pretty unreadable and easily cut off in a comment. It looks like you might have a [UTF-8 problem](http://owasp-modsecurity-core-rule-set.owasp.narkive.com/p0gg2qEL/rule-id-981318-sql-injection-problem) with your WAP configuration (it's a partial match). Why you'd not have that with a private browsing session I'm not sure. It looks like you might need to adjust your security policy for your application?

Comment: noo I think that i need to just ignore the block of my ip or something like this